# Xdebug 3 on Docker its installed but the breakpoints doesn't work

Tags: php, docker, nginx, xdebug

I've installed Xdebug on Docker and it look like it's correctly installed if check `phpinfo()` but when I set a breakpoint in VSCode the execution doesn't stop.

I'm using an `nginx` container as web server, it worked on `apache` but not on `nginx`

This is the `php-ini-overrides.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 108M

[Xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

And this is the `launch.json` from VSCode:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   
    "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
       
            {
                "name": "Listen for XDebug",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "port": 9003,
                "pathMappings": {
                "/usr/share/nginx/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: If you debug a script containing xdebug_info(), what does it say? FWIW, you don't need to set `xdebug.idekey`.

Comment: `xdebug_info()` show this error `Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 172.19.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), host.docker.internal:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Comment: And is Xdebug and PHP running in a Linux based docker *host* ? Because `host.docker.internal` doesn't work there, unless you make an extra setting (in a new enough Docker engine only).

Comment: its running on windows host

Comment: Then your IDE is either not listening, or has a firewall blocking port 9003 or something so that Xdebug can't connect. You can run `netstat -abno | find "9003" | find "LISTEN"` to find out whether it is. Perhaps it also gives you the IP address it's listening on.

Comment: And FWIW, having `xdebug.discover_client_host=true` is usually pointless with Docker, so I'd recommend to remove it.

Comment: I don't get any result with netstat -abno | find "9003" | find "LISTEN"

Comment: Well, that means that your editor isn't listening then, and that's your problem.

Comment: @al_fg If you see no results after running that command (has to be in `cmd` and not powershell BTW), then you must have missed some step as VSCode is NOT listening for PHP debugging. I suggest you do this: 1) get any screen recoding tool (e.g. ShareX or any other; there are plenty free ones) 2) launch this project in VSCode; 3) Start recording; 4) try to debug -- it should show what you are clicking / show how VSCode window (Debug panel in particular) looks when you are trying to debug and it does not work. An dtry to run that `netstat` command again (in Windows ofc).